# Angular 2: is not a function but it exist

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get an array out of a different class but he says the function does not exist.
here is my code:

**courses.component.ts**:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {CourseService} from './course.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
        <h2>Courses</h2>
        {{ title }}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor ="#course of courses">
            {{course}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        `,
    providers: [CourseService]
})
export class CoursesComponent{
    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;

    constructor(courseService: CourseService){
        this.courses = CourseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

**course.service.ts**:

```
export class CourseService{
    getCourses() : string[]{
        return ["Course1","Course2","Course3"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that probably as well, depends on what he tries to accomplish.

Comment: restarting the dev server fixed it for me, inexplicable!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reference the argument name, not the argument type

```
 this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
                ^ lower case c
```

Comment: It still gives the same error: TypeError: courseService.getCourses is not a function

Comment: where should I past that?

Comment: first line inside the constructor (before the line from my answer)

Comment: Change `;` to `:` in ` getCourses() ; string[]{`. Also you should get an output from the `console.log(courseService);` if you have added it in the constructor before `this.courses = courseService.getCourses();`.

Comment: I edited the question assuming that was a mistake, shout have noted it, ^

Comment: Thanks it was the ;, I never see those small errors

Answer (score 2):

I think it's some kind of bug, because TypeScript recognize me the method but when I delete and type the method again getCourses() in the component, it says that the method is not found, then I go to the Service and start to delete blank lines, and the method Works. I'm currently using Angular 4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same inexplicable problem. I copy and pasted the code from the web and something must not have been right in the function declaration. I deleted the line

`getCourses(): string[] {`

and typed it out again by hand. When I ran the code, it worked. Maybe some invisible character was pasted in and messing up Typescript? Who knows.